# Access DeviceOrientationEvent properties data Alpha, Beta, Gamma and Absolute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[DeviceOrientation Event Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/#deviceorientation)

[MDN Detecting device orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation)

[HTML5 for the Mobile Web: Device Orientation Events](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-mobile-web-device-orientation-events)

I am trying to get the `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma` properties' **values** of the `deviceorientation` event with jQuery.

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
  var alpha = event.alpha;
  var beta = event.beta;
  var gamma = event.gamma;
  alert(event.alpha + ' : ' + event.beta + ' : ' + event.gamma);
}, false);
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).on('deviceorientation', function(event){

    // var alpha = event.alpha;
    // alert (alpha);
    // results in undefined

    var alphaVal = $('deviceorientation').val('alpha');
    alert(alphaVal);
    // results in object

    // var alphaVal = $('deviceorientation').attr('alpha');
    // results in undefined   

});
```

No matter what I try I either get `undefined` or an `object` as a result instead of the value for `alpha`.

How can I access the orientation data of the deviceorientation event properties with jQuery? `.val()`, `.attr()` and `.prop()` dont seem to work or I am doing something wrong with the `deviceorientation` event?

Comment: peek inside the callback's values with `console.log(event)`. you don't use jq to reach them, they are normal dot path-based object properties.

Comment: What are "dot path-based object properties" ? Do you mean something like this: stackoverflow.com/a/8817461/1010918 ? When you say "you don't use jq to reach them" do you mean it "is not possible" or do you mean "do more research about dot path-based object properties". Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: Also, simply using `alert(event)` also gives me an `object`. Using `alert` since I am seeing the results directly on the PDA running the site on a local LAMP stack and have not set up remote debugging. So just loading the IP of the host and the site gets served. Would not know how to check the PDA's console. In any case for this `alert` should also work, though I still get `object` in the alert instead of the value of the event property.

Comment: the object is the event... try `alert(Object.keys(event));`